# Trying to refactor MUI's enhanced table to be generic

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to refactor MUI's enhanced table to be generic. Originally, their HeadCell definition looked like:

```
interface HeadCell {
  disablePadding: boolean;
  id: keyof Data;
  label: string;
  numeric: boolean;
}
```

But I turned it into:

```
interface HeadCell <T> {
  disablePadding: boolean;
  id: keyof T;
  label: string;
  numeric: boolean;
}
```

No errors so far, so seems fine. Problem is, I don't know how to dynamically generate the columns based off of the generic type.

In very wrong code, I'm trying to do the following:

```
const headCells: readonly HeadCell<T>[] = Object.keys(T).map((key) => {});
```

How would this be done correctly?